# ¿Por qué si uso render_template en Flask me rmuestra una página con fondo negro y etiquetas HTML?

Tags: python, flask

Tengo una duda con respecto al uso de render_template.
He estado siguiendo un par de tutoriales para implementarlo, el problema es que cuando accedo a la URL correspondiente me aparece una página con un fondo negro y el contenido con las etiquetas HTML.

Me refiero que cuando corro la app, se ve así:
`<!DOCTYPE html>`
y eso no se debe ver, porque aparecen todas las etiquetas HTML.

He intentado los 3 puntos con esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65318395/how-to-render-html-for-variables-in-flask-render-template)

app.py

```
    @app.route('/')
    def index():
       return render_template('index.html', message="hello world!")
    if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

templates/index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>API</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="flashes">

                {{ message | safe }}

    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

La estructura de mis carpetas está así:

```
TestAPI/
├── venv
├── templates/
│   └── index.html
├── app.py
```